# Adding an editor tab to SurveyJS - not able to bind to model

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, surveyjs

I'm experimenting with adding an application specific tab to SurveyJS, which isn't natively supported.  What I've done so far is adding a Recipients Model, e.g.:

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

export class RecipientsModel {
    public firstName: string = 'Chris';
    constructor() {}
    public show() {}
}
```

And a template (recipients.html):

```
<script type="text/html" id="recipients">
  <div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-bulk-accounts">
    <label class="control-label" for="edit-bulk-accounts">Email addresses <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea class="form-control form-textarea required" id="edit-bulk-accounts" name="bulk_accounts" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
    <div class="description">Email addresses for participants you would like to register.  Enter one per line.</div>
  </div>
  <span data-bind="text: firstName">Test</span>
</script>
```

I've modified editor.ts so that my tab shows, and the content is populated:

```
this.recipient = new RecipientsModel();
...
...
...
public showManageRecipients() {
    if (!this.canSwitchViewType(null)) return;
    this.recipient.firstName = 'Chris';
    // this.showSurveyRecipients();
    this.koViewType("recipients")
}
```

So, with what I have so far I have a tab that shows the static content I want.  The next step is to figure out the binding which is currently broken:

```
knockout-min.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return { name:'recipients'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return firstName }"
Message: firstName is not defined
at text (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-min.js:68), <anonymous>:3:57)
at update (knockout-min.js:98)
at function.a.B.i (knockout-min.js:72)
at Function.Pc (knockout-min.js:51)
at Function.Qc (knockout-min.js:51)
at Function.aa (knockout-min.js:50)
at Object.a.m.a.B (knockout-min.js:49)
at knockout-min.js:72
at Object.q (knockout-min.js:11)
at m (knockout-min.js:71)
```

As this is my first time messing with either KnockoutJS or SurveyJS, I'm struggling to make this simple binding of a property work.  I'm currently going through KnockoutJS documentation but, again, I'm not sure this is the correct path of debugging.

**EDIT**
After more debugging, I've updated my model to set `firstName` to a `ko.observable`: `firstName = ko.observable("");`.  And, within SurveyJs codebase I set it using `this.recipient.firstName('Chris');`.  I am now able to use: `<span data-bind="text: recipient.firstName">Test</span>` which is *OK* - but I think I should somehow be binding the model in a way that doesn't required the use of `recipient.firstName` and I can just use `firstName`.  Maybe I'm wrong.
**END EDIT**

So, my main question at this point: **How do I make the binding of this.recipient.firstName work in my template?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the binding context using the [`with`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) binding:

```
<script type="text/html" id="recipients">
  <div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-bulk-accounts">
    <label class="control-label" for="edit-bulk-accounts">Email addresses <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea class="form-control form-textarea required" id="edit-bulk-accounts" name="bulk_accounts" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
    <div class="description">Email addresses for participants you would like to register.  Enter one per line.</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ko with: recipient -->
  <span data-bind="text: firstName">Test</span>
  <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated:

Since 1.0.69 you can add a custom tab into SurveyJS Editor (Builder) via the following code:

```
  editor.tabs.push({
    name: "custom",
    title: "Custom Tab",
    template: "custom-template-id",
    data: {
      data: "Custom data"
    },
    action: () => {
      if (!editor.canSwitchViewType(null)) return;
      editor.koViewType("custom");
    }
  });
```

You need also to add a corresponding template:

```
  <script type="text/html" id="custom-template-id">
    <div data-bind="text: data">
    </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: Might be missing it, but not sure how this addresses the question.  I'm not looking to add a property editor but a tab, e.g. adjacent "Test Survey", so the tabs, in your example, would be: "Survey Designer", "JSON Editor", "Test Survey", "My Custom Tab"

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Oh, I see now. Yes, It's another task. I can take a look on monday if you still need the solution

Comment: if you have a solution for adding the tab that doesn't involve hacking SurveyJS core I'd love to see that; however, that's not within the scope of this question.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisRockwell This functionality has been implemented since 1.0.69

Comment: This is awesome @TSV.  Doesn't look like it's been tagged yet (https://github.com/surveyjs/editor/releases) so I'll check back in a couple days.  I have already added 2 custom tabs but I'll definitely update and redo my work this way. Thanks!